# Scapy, RST packets and iptables

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, scapy, tcpdump

I wrote a script that basically does the following: Opens a socket, connects and then an object that parses this socket so I can play around with scapy. It turns out that the packets are arriving to my destination but the responses from the destination host back to me are lost "somewhere" "somehow". I can see from the dump of the destination host that it clearly replies with some RST packets back, however from my "attacking" host I cant see these RST packets. Is this related to my TCP/IP stack and the generation of these RST packets locally or what? Do I have to set up an iptables rule for solving this problem?

I have the following snippet from my script

```
         for i in range (0,int(args.packets)):
                time.sleep(5)
                ans,unans=sr(IP(dst=args.dst)/TCP(dport=int(args.port))/fuzz(Raw()), timeout=0.5,  inter=0, iface=args.interface)
                unans.nsummary()
                ans.nsummary()
```

Another issue is that supposedly this is using the fuzz() method from scapy and it fuzzes the actual payload of the packet (not the IP / TCP header ). However when I am listening with netcat for example nothing is getting printed and I can also see from the dump that the packets are getting interpreted to either FTP-DATA or something other...

Any help?

Comment: You're asking two distinct questions and I think you should focus on one and open another question for the second.